# Flatten sequence of numeric values by threshold with rxjs

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

Using rxjs, I got an observable sequence of floating point numbers. Now I want to filter out smaller variations in the stream and only emit a value if it is a certain amount larger than a previously emitted value.

In other words: The first value in the sequence is always emitted. Then, each emitted (=non-filtered) value should be at least larger than the previously **emitted** value by *delta*. Any value not matching that criteria is filtered.

I have already come up with a solution that does what I want as described above:

```
var obs = Rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {
  /* ... */
});

var last;

obs.map(function(value) {
  if (last === undefined) {
    last = value;
    return value;
  } else {
      var threshold = 0.5,
          delta = Math.abs(last - value);

      if (delta > threshold) {
        last = value;
        return value;
      }
      else {
        return undefined;
      }
    }
  }).
  filter(function(value) {
    return value !== undefined;
  });
```

I'm new to rxjs and reactive programming, and I think the above solution is overly complicated. More importantly, it violates a principle of reactive programming that says *do not save state outside the composed pipeline*. But I do that, as I am keeping track via the `last` variable and want to get rid of that.

How can I fix this and do it the reactive way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scan` to manage your state:

```
var filtered = obs.scan({}, function (acc, value) {
    if (acc.value !== undefined) {
        var threshold = 0.5,
            change = Math.abs(acc.value - value);

        if (change < threshold) {
            return { value: acc.value, isValid: false };
        }
    }

    return { value: value, isValid: true };
})
.filter(function (acc) { return acc.isValid; })
.map(function (acc) { return acc.value; });
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered, but if you find yourself doing this a lot, you could roll your own. Just spitballing because it's an interesting utility:

```
Observable.prototype.maxThreshold = function(threshold, selector) {
  var last = null;
  return this.filter(function(x) {
    var n = selector ? selector(x) : x;
    var delta = Math.abs(n - last);
    if(last === null || delta > threshold) {
      last = n;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

Which could be used as follows:

```
streamOfNumbers.maxThreshold(0.5).
  subscribe(function(x) {
    console.log(x);
  });
```

or

```
streamOfObjects.maxThreshold(0.5, function(x) { return x.value; }).
  subscribe(function(x) {
    console.log(x);
  });
```